# Make postback when the OkButton in a ModalPopup is clicked in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net-ajax, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I follow the example in [Atlas: Creating a Confirmation Using the ModalPopup Extender](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/alanl/archive/2006/07/25/Creating_a_Confirmation_Using_the_ModalPopup_Extender.aspx) to make a postback when the OkButton in a ModalPopup is clicked (it uses the ModalPopupExtender that comes in ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit), but as I can see, the Sys.WebForms.PostBackAction() is no longer present in ASP.NET AJAX (the example is for Atlas). When I run it the "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" error message raises, in the line in javascript where I create the PostBackAction. How can I make this works in ASP.NET AJAX, or maybe, there's another way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about using the [ConfirmButtonExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx)? You get the modal "bling" through the extender, and you'll have the PostBack processing you need.

You wire the button click event as normal for processing, but the Confirm extender will "intercept" the processing and allow things to continue if the user confirms the action.

Comment: I think this will have the same problem.

Comment: By using the Confirm Extender, you would't have to script anything in JavaScript to call a post back. You simply wire up your button to process your server side code, and the extender will only allow that to process if the user confirms it. It is kind of a flip-flop from what your current setup is, as far as I can tell from your question. Maybe post some code?

Answer (score 5):

Server side events do work with the ModalPopupExtender. What you need to do is to create a button with a display style set to none. Then set the TargetControlID property of the ModalPopupExtender to the hidden button ID.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClick="btnShowModal_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
<ajaxControlToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="btnHidden" PopupControlID="divId" />
```

In the OnClick handler show the modal:

```
modalExtender.Show();
```

In the handler for the control that will close the modal (usually a button) hide the modal:

```
modalExtender.Hide();
```

I'm able to successfully use this method for posting back to the server in order to populate controls in my modal with info from a database during the postback. Works like a champ.

Comment: You are a legend! This should have been the answer

Answer (score 2):

If I remember the ModalPopupExtender correctly, it has an OKControlID that you set as your button ID.

Could you not just assign your button on "onclick" clientside handler that calls a postback?

For example, something like:

```
 myModalPopupExtender.OkButtonID = myOKButton.ID;
 string script = ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference(myOKButton, myOKButton.ID);

 myOKButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

**EDIT**:  It looks like [another potential solution here.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1218424.aspx)

Comment: Yes you would think so, but no. The OnClick() does not fire up. Try it yourself! I am using VS2005 ASP.net 2. The only way to force it is as per @Tim's answer above or to place a jquery function call to force a postback from a javascript function call, which can be called from onclick().

Answer (score 2):

You can place an in-visible button in the panel and set it as OkButton. Add your actual button in the panel and add its OnClick event handler. See code below:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender 
TargetControlID="btnSubmit"
DropShadow="true"
OkControlID="btnOK"
CancelControlID="btnDecline"
PopupControlID="pnlTermsAndConditions"
BackgroundCssClass="popup"
ID="ModalPopupExtender1" 
runat="server">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTermsAndConditions" runat="server">
<table width="500" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="white">
<tr>
    <td><b>Tables and Content</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TermsAndCondition" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Columns="60">
    This is my terms and condoition
    </asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text=" Accept " OnClick="btnAccept_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnDecline" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text=" Decline " />
    <asp:Button ID="btnOK" style="display:none;visible:false;" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text=" OK " />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I have been looking for.  Great post.  Incidentally, it is not neccessary to create the mock OK button.  Just don't include the optional OKbutton prameter in the Modal Popup Extension definition.

Comment: Per Mark's comment, I finally got a postback to the server when I removed the optional OKButton from the modal popup extender. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Hmm that didn't work for me. @Mark, could you please post the code of your extender here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just adding a server side OnClick event to the button? This should post back the whole form. 
Or you could get the main form from html ($find('myFormName') or something) and do a .submit() on it.

Comment: The server sides events don't work, because it uses the ModalPopupExtender