# How to fire C# code from JavaScript (ModalPopupExtender/ajaxToolkit)

Tags: javascript, ajax, c#-3.0

I am using ASP.NET/C# Framework 3.5/SQL Server with AjaxControlToolkit's ModalPopupExtender to freeze the main window.

The use-case is that when a user clicks the Break Button, the screen have to be frozen, which I am able to do so by using ModalPopupExtender. But then in the ModalPopupExtender  I have given two buttons as follows:-

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
    DropShadow="true"
    X="500"
    Y="100"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    OkControlID="btnBack"
    OnOkScript="BackButton_Click()"
    CancelControlID="btnCancel"
    OnCancelScript="CancelButton_Click()"
    PopupControlID="Panel1"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel3"
    TargetControlID="lbn_job_det">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In the PopupWindow I have two buttons,

1. Back from Break and
2. Cancel.

While on clicking of Back button, I need to do insertion in DB.

I searched a lot for the workarounds, but found nothing, some blogs said to create an Ajax-based website, and some used to say create a Web Service.

The C# Code is as follows:-

```
public string BackFromBreak(string argument)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Redirected from BackFromBreak";
    if (argument == "back")
    {
        return "endbreak";
    } 
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call c# code directly from javascript in a Web app simply because they run in two different places, server side and client side respectively.  So you have to decide.  If you want to call some server side logic from javascript(i.e. ajax) or do a complete postback to execute de c# code.  Best regards

Comment: Thanks Igor Zelaya! <br/>So as you stated, if I want to do PostBack, then how would it be implemented in my scenario ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809222/make-postback-when-the-okbutton-in-a-modalpopup-is-clicked-in-asp-net-ajax